# How to route traffic to different interfaces for different ports

Tags: routing, interface

I have an `eth0` connection providing internet connection through a proxy server only for port 80 and 443 (provided by university). For `ssh`, `git` and related purposes, I got a different connection on my mobile connected to the laptop through `wlan0` (or `usb0` through tethering.)

I need to route all connections for port 80 and 443 through `eth0` ethernet while the rest of the ports should connect through `wlan0` or `usb0`.

I have searched online but only found about routing specific servers through specific interfaces using route command.

How to do a similar thing for different ports?

Comment: What OS are you using?